# Jmeter - How load HTTP Body text from file directory

Tags: soap, directory, jmeter, performance-testing

I have multiple HTTP body data saved in couple of text files in one directory. I need to load that HTTP body data from those files which in that directory into SOAP request via jmeter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get the file names into a JMeter Variable is using [Directory Listing Config](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/introducing-directory-listing-config-plugin-jmeter) plugin

[image]

Once done you can reference each and every file content using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) like:

```
${__FileToString(${body},,)}
```

[image]

This way each virtual user will send the content of the next file on each iteration:

[image]